# how to change a perticular content in html page on button click using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I do have a `Form` in which  detail like `name`, `Contact No.` etc. are taken in textboxes and a `Submit` button is there.
I wish to open a `div` for example `<div> I Am Here </div>`as well as the previous `form` should be hidden on `Submit`.

As i have taken reference from the tutorial ([angular_routing](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)) in which `angular routing`has been used.But in this case url address got changed which is not matching with my requirement.

i have an another reffrence as [sendotp](https://sendotp.msg91.com/), which is exactly what i want, in which they hide current view and showing the next view on button click and url address has been remained same.

according to me second one is better because instead of loading the whole page only a certain part has been making a difference.But need suggesstions, one suits best in `angularjs`.

**Can i have a prominent solution to do that by using `angularjs`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `myForm.$submitted`

```
<form name="myForm" ng-hide="myForm.$submitted"></form>
<div ng-show="myForm.$submitted"> I Am Here </div>
```

Comment: hey! @salih thanks for your support . Can you please help me out that how can i use `ng-hide` and `ng-show` within `controller` section as per `$http.post().success`.

Comment: You can define a variable like $scope.showSomething and then use it in html like ng-show="showSomething"

Comment: hey! @Salih Şenol Çakarcı. I need a help from your side. please a look to this issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348123/how-to-prevent-showing-login-page-after-user-logged-and-hit-browser-back-button