# how to prevent showing login page after user logged and hit browser back button without using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, angular-factory

I am new to anglularjs platform. I am creating a `log-in application`. I am facing a problem in which all things are going right but got stuck in to manage that if user is already logged in and trying to open same url in different tab it redirect the user directly to `dashbord page(dashboard.html)`, but when i press `browser back button`, instead of going previous page, it opens `login page(login_admin.html)`.
scenario is like as follows:

1. localhost:8080 --> it opens --> login_admin.html (achieved).
2. entering credential and on submit --> opens --> dashboard.html (achieved).
3. on entering same url(localhost:8080) in different tab (suppose previously opened facebook.com) ---> opens --> dashbord.html (achieved).
4. on pressing browser back button, instead of going `facebook.com`,  it opens login_admin.html (unresolved).
   suggest some solution please.

my js code is as follows:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']);
console.log("in appnew.js")

app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:  'login_admin.html',
        controller: 'userController'


    })
    .when('/dashboard',{
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller: 'userController',
        authenticated: true


    })
    .when('/logout',{
        templateUrl: 'logout_admin.html',
         controller: 'userController'


    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: "/"
    });
});

app.controller('userController',function($scope,$location,userModel){

    angular.extend($scope,{
      login: function(adminfrm){
        var data={
        jeeb_no: $scope.admin.name,
        password: $scope.admin.password
    };


      userModel.login(data).then(function(){
        $location.path('/dashboard');
      });
      },
      logout: function(){
        userModel.doUserLogout();
        $location.path('/');
      }
    });


});

app.run(["$rootScope",'$location','userModel', function($rootScope,$location,userModel,$window){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current){
        console.log("event: %j",event);
        console.log("next: %j",next);
        console.log('current: %j',current);
      if (next.$$route.authenticated) {
          console.log("next.$$route.authenticated"+next.$$route.authenticated);
          console.log('userModel.getAuthStatus app.run if 1'+userModel.getAuthStatus());


        if (!userModel.getAuthStatus()) {
            console.log("getAuthStatus"+userModel.getAuthStatus);
            console.log('userModel.getAuthStatus app.run if 1(1)'+userModel.getAuthStatus());
            $location.path('/');
        }
      }

      if (next.$$route.originalPath =='/') {
        console.log("next.$$route.originalPath  "+next.$$route.originalPath);
        if (userModel.getAuthStatus()) {
            console.log("current "+current);
            console.log("next "+next);
            next.$$route.originalPath = '/dashboard'
            $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);

        }
    }
});
}]);



app.factory('userModel', function($http,$cookies,$location){
   var userModel={};
   userModel.login= function(loginfrm){
    data={
      jeeb_no: loginfrm.jeeb_no,
      //password: loginfrm.jeeb_no
    };
     $cookies.put('auth',data);
    console.log("loginfrm"+loginfrm);
    return $http.post("http://1/admin_login", data).
    success(function(response){

       /*console.log('$scope.dynamic1: %j', $scope);*/
       console.log("response success: %j",response)

    }).
    error(function(response){
        console.log("response error:",response);
    });
   };
    userModel.getAuthStatus = function(){
        var status = $cookies.get('auth');
        console.log('status: %j', status);
        if(status){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    };
    console.log('userModel.getAuthStatus'+userModel.getAuthStatus());
    userModel.doUserLogout = function(){
        $cookies.remove('auth');
    }
    console.log("userModel: %j",userModel);
    return userModel;
})
```

Comment: could you please create a snippet of this example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove page from history, so "back" will work properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441698/remove-page-from-history-so-back-will-work-properly)

Comment: the duplicate I posted has alternatives that don't use ionic framework, notably the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36348261/2495283) from Rebecca